# How to find the min value in the last matrix row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I'm working with matrixs on python and I'm not sure how I can find the min value in the last row.

So if I have a 2D matrix `mat` with the values x,y that I get with:

```
[x, y] = mat.shape
```

How can I get the min value from the last row?

Thanks in advance and sorry If my english is not good enough.

Comment: If the answer below solved your question, please mark it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the last row with the index -1 and then use the min function like this:

```
min(mat[-1])
```